# Having issues with C using float and printf

Tags: c, io, floating-point, printf, stdio

I'm trying to run some basic code in C to declare 2 float variables, and then divide them and put that value in the 3rd variable. After this I print all 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  /* variable definition: */
  float a, b, c; 
  /* variable initialization */
  a = 1.2;
  b = 2.7;  
  c = a / b;
  printf("Floats (a,b) and quotient (c) are : %d,%d,%d \n", a,b,c);  
   return 0;
}
```

I'm using the online compiler "www.ideone.com" to compile and run the code, and this is the result I'm getting:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 2156 signal:0
```

Floats (a,b) and quotient (c) are : 1073741824,1072902963,-1610612736

Can anyone see if perhaps I made a mistake in the code? It's for a class and everything worked fine for every step of directions until I changed from int to float.

Comment: %d expects integer arguments, see the printf documentation.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/  %d is for integers, %f for floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print floats, thus change this:

```
printf("Floats (a,b) and quotient (c) are : %d,%d,%d \n", a,b,c);
```

to this:

```
printf("Floats (a,b) and quotient (c) are : %f,%f,%f \n", a,b,c);
```

For more, check the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect, I had no idea I needed to do that, or that it was specific to a certain data type!

Comment: Now you know @RickHammer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

`%d` is not a correct conversion for float, use `%f` instead

change:

```
printf("Floats (a,b) and quotient (c) are : %d,%d,%d \n", a,b,c);
```

to:

```
printf("Floats (a,b) and quotient (c) are : %f,%f,%f \n", a,b,c);
```

and you should be fine.